# Dependent QComboBoxes in a QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to link 3 different comboboxes in Pyqt5 inside a qtablewidget. the first 2 are linked in one slot and the third one is linked to the second combobox using a different slot in a separate definition. On the change of the first combobox, the 2nd combobox changes which makes the 3rd one change (similar to car selection websites).

The current issue is that on change of the first combobox the second signal also executes which makes it execute twice and giving me dictionary key error as the first execution doesnt include the key. The error occurs on Line 81 when trying to access the dictionary.
See the image as it runs the index twice:

[image]

**Attempt**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox, QMainWindow, QApplication, QFileDialog


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.m_tablewidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(0, 3)
        self.m_tablewidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(
            ["Col 1", "Col 2", "Col 3"]
        )
        self.m_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Add Row", clicked=self.onClicked)

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        lay.addWidget(self.m_tablewidget)
        lay.addWidget(self.m_button, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.vehicleHardware_dict = {'k': ['LiftSource_Wing_ChordConstantChordTapered', 'TPS_Active_Coolant'], 'X51': ['TPS_Passive_Tile', 'ThrustSource_Airbreathing_ScramjetTwoD']}
        self.procesVeh_dict = {'k': ['Aerodynamics', 'Optimization', 'Propulsion', 'Weight_Balance'], 'X51': ['Aerodynamics', 'Optimization', 'Propulsion', 'Weight_Balance']}
        self.processMethod_dict = {'Aerodynamics': ['kia', 'T1_case2_outNoIn'], 'Optimization': ['thomas'], 'Propulsion': ['test', 'rocket', 'T1_case3_InOutSame_inLess'], 'Weight_Balance': ['wing weight', 'T1_case1_inNoOut', 'T1_case3_inOutEq_inMore']}
        self.methodInput_dict = {'T1_case1_inNoOut': ['T'], 'T1_case2_outNoIn': [], 'T1_case3_InOutSame_inLess': ['T'], 'T1_case3_inOutEq_inMore': ['THRUST_REF'], 'kia': ['ACS', 'AEXIT', 'AE_AT', 'AIP', 'AISP', 'AISP_AVAIL_V', 'AISP_EFF', 'AISP_EFF_V', 'THETA2_N'], 'rocket': ['AIP', 'AISP', 'AISP_AVAIL_V', 'AISP_EFF', 'AISP_EFF_V', 'AISP_HW', 'AISP_REF'], 'test': ['ACS', 'Y_V'], 'thomas': ['ACS', 'AEXIT', 'AE_AT', 'AIP', 'AISP', 'AISP_AVAIL_V', 'CS', 'DIA_BODY'], 'wing weight': ['A', 'ABASE', 'ACAP', 'ACAP_SPLN', 'ACS', 'AEXIT', 'AE_AT']}

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def onClicked(self):
        combobox1_vehicle = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        combobox2_hardware = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        # combo_dummy = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        for k, v in self.processMethod_dict.items():
            combobox1_vehicle.addItem(k, v)
            for kk, vv in self.methodInput_dict.items():
                combobox2_hardware.addItem(kk, vv)

        combobox3 = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        combobox3.addItems(combobox2_hardware.currentData())

        combobox1_vehicle.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.onCurrentTextChanged1)
        combobox2_hardware.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.onCurrentTextChanged2)

        rc = self.m_tablewidget.rowCount()
        self.m_tablewidget.insertRow(rc)

        for i, combo in enumerate((combobox1_vehicle, combobox2_hardware, combobox3)):
            self.m_tablewidget.setCellWidget(rc, i, combo)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def onCurrentTextChanged1(self):
        combobox1_vehicle = self.sender()
        if not isinstance(combobox1_vehicle, QtWidgets.QComboBox):
            return
        p = combobox1_vehicle.mapTo(self.m_tablewidget.viewport(), QtCore.QPoint())
        ix = self.m_tablewidget.indexAt(p)
        if not ix.isValid() or ix.column() != 0:
            return
        r = ix.row()
        data = combobox1_vehicle.currentData()
        combobox2_hardware = self.m_tablewidget.cellWidget(r, 1)
        if not isinstance(combobox2_hardware, QtWidgets.QComboBox):
            return
        combobox2_hardware.clear()
        combobox2_hardware.addItems(data)


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def onCurrentTextChanged2(self):
        combobox2_hardware = self.sender()
        if not isinstance(combobox2_hardware, QtWidgets.QComboBox):
            return
        p = combobox2_hardware.mapTo(self.m_tablewidget.viewport(), QtCore.QPoint())
        ix = self.m_tablewidget.indexAt(p)
        if not ix.isValid() or ix.column() != 1:
            return
        r = ix.row()
        # data = combobox2_hardware.currentData()
        valueOfKey = combobox2_hardware.currentText()
        print(combobox2_hardware)
        print(p)
        print(ix)

        data = self.methodInput_dict[valueOfKey]
        combobox3 = self.m_tablewidget.cellWidget(r, 2)
        if not isinstance(combobox3, QtWidgets.QComboBox):
            return
        combobox3.clear()
        if data == None:
            combobox3.addItem("")
        else:
            combobox3.addItems(data)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I have a question, if Aerodynamics is chosen in the first combobox, and then the option T1_case2_outNoIn of the second combobox is chosen, what should be shown in the third combobox?

Comment: The values of self.methodInput_dict , each dict is key and val of the current and next dict

Comment: But the value is an empty list

Comment: In the event that there is nothing at that key location the value of combobox 3 is empty bracket, otherwise it should be the values based on the combo 2 being the key for the dict of values for combo 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases where there is a lot of information it is necessary to look for a data structure that handles the information. In this case you could use a `QAbstractItemModel` to share all the QComboBox of the same row, and to change what is shown you should use the [`setRootModelIndex()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#setRootModelIndex) method. In the following example I added a `QTreeView` so you can see how the model is distributed.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

d = {
    "Aerodynamics": {
        "kia": [
            "ACS",
            "AEXIT",
            "AE_AT",
            "AIP",
            "AISP",
            "AISP_AVAIL_V",
            "AISP_EFF",
            "AISP_EFF_V",
            "THETA2_N",
        ],
        "T1_case2_outNoIn": [],
    },
    "Optimization": {
        "thomas": [
            "ACS",
            "AEXIT",
            "AE_AT",
            "AIP",
            "AISP",
            "AISP_AVAIL_V",
            "CS",
            "DIA_BODY",
        ]
    },
    "Propulsion": {
        "test": ["ACS", "Y_V"],
        "rocket": [
            "AIP",
            "AISP",
            "AISP_AVAIL_V",
            "AISP_EFF",
            "AISP_EFF_V",
            "AISP_HW",
            "AISP_REF",
        ],
        "T1_case3_InOutSame_inLess": ["T"],
    },
    "Weight_Balance": {
        "wing weight": [
            "A",
            "ABASE",
            "ACAP",
            "ACAP_SPLN",
            "ACS",
            "AEXIT",
            "AE_AT",
        ],
        "T1_case1_inNoOut": ["T"],
        "T1_case3_inOutEq_inMore": ["THRUST_REF"],
    },
}


def dict_to_model(item, d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            it = QtGui.QStandardItem(k)
            item.appendRow(it)
            dict_to_model(it, v)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for v in d:
            dict_to_model(item, v)
    else:
        item.appendRow(QtGui.QStandardItem(str(d)))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.m_tablewidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(0, 3)
        self.m_tablewidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(
            ["Col 1", "Col 2", "Col 3"]
        )
        self.m_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Add Row", clicked=self.onClicked)
        self.m_treeview = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        dict_to_model(model.invisibleRootItem(), d)
        self.m_treeview.setModel(model)
        self.m_treeview.expandAll()

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        lay.addWidget(self.m_tablewidget)
        lay.addWidget(self.m_treeview)
        lay.addWidget(self.m_button, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def onClicked(self):
        rc = self.m_tablewidget.rowCount()
        self.m_tablewidget.insertRow(rc)

        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        dict_to_model(model.invisibleRootItem(), d)

        it = model.invisibleRootItem()
        combos = []
        for i in range(3):
            combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
            combo.setModel(model)
            ix = model.indexFromItem(it)
            combo.setRootModelIndex(ix)
            combo.setCurrentIndex(0)
            it = it.child(0)
            self.m_tablewidget.setCellWidget(rc, i, combo)
            combos.append(combo)

        for combo in combos:
            combo.currentIndexChanged[int].connect(self.onCurrentIndexChanged)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def onCurrentIndexChanged(self, index):
        combo = self.sender()
        if not isinstance(combo, QtWidgets.QComboBox):
            return
        p = combo.mapTo(self.m_tablewidget.viewport(), QtCore.QPoint())
        ix = self.m_tablewidget.indexAt(p)
        if not ix.isValid():
            return
        r, c = ix.row(), ix.column()
        if c == (self.m_tablewidget.columnCount() - 1):
            return
        model = combo.model()
        combo2 = self.m_tablewidget.cellWidget(r, c + 1)
        ix = combo.rootModelIndex()
        child_ix = model.index(index, 0, ix)
        combo2.setRootModelIndex(child_ix)
        combo2.setCurrentIndex(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Any idea why it was running twice?

Comment: @Kevin_ALA Actually I do not want to analyze your code, it is not the most orderly I have seen making the code difficult to read, I recommend working on it.

Comment: Thanks, well noted! just a rookie trying to put pieces together and learn as I go